# How to specify a sub-range within sheets to execute sendEmails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Noob here. I'm trying to automate sending of emails using a database of many names and email addresses, but I want to not send all emails in the database at once, but rather specify a range of names and emails to send (e.g. to email addresses in rows 2-15) using a unique trigger (or script?) at a certain time, and then send another range of emails (e.g. rows 16-30) using another unique trigger or script and so on (this is due to email limits). The script I'm using is set up to send all emails in the database at once.

```
    function sendEmail() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
var subject = sheet2.getRange(2,1).getValue();
var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();
var name=sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
var message = sheet2.getRange(2,2).getValue();

message=message.replace("<name>",name);
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {name:"WordProfessors"});
}


}
```

Comment: If they’re not all contiguous you could use range list otherwise just range

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a bried description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the term you are looking for is "**batching**".

One way to accomplish this is to create some form of a queue. You can add a column to your data to denote their processing state.

1. In your function, you'd first sort your data by "unprocessed" first.
2. Then sends out a maximum of `n = Math.min(sheet1.getLastRow(), 10)` 10 emails.
3. Once all the emails are sent, mark all those as "processed" so they are sorted to the end next time the script starts.

I would remind you to avoid calling Spreadsheet API functions in a loop because of the performance penalty. Instead, you should get the entire range of cells `const range = sheet1.getRange(1, 1, n, 2)` and perform actions on that range like getting the 2D array of values: `range.getValues()` and looping over those.

Comment: Hi Sunny, thanks for your answer: I have implemented the method you describe and it works fine. I have a question about your suggestion of using a 2D array instead of looping over the spreadsheet. I don't really understand how or why, I guess I will need to do some more research on how to implement that method. Would not doing so explain why I am getting the error: 'Service invoked too many times for one day' when I run the function? Is this exceeding the daily quotas? seems strange as it occurs after sending 100 emails using the looping function

Comment: You've probably exceeded the quote for sending emails to multiple recipients. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas. I suggest you use upgrade your account type or utilize multiple accounts.